# why node js socket not working when change port to https?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, protocols

Normally in `app.js` i use this code on port `3000` it's work good (on `my-domain.com:3000`).

.

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('start server on port :3000');
});
```

then i want to use on `https`, so i change `app.js` to

```
http.listen(443, function(){
    console.log('start server on port :443');
});
```

When run `node app.js` , it's show error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1252:14)
    at listen (net.js:1288:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1384:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/admin/web/my-domain.com/public_html/app.js:28:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

Normally i have to access to `my-domain.com:3000` for user chat. So i want to know how can i access to `https://www.my-domain.com` for user chat ?

Comment: You should also know that just changing the port to 443 does not make your server work with https either.  You have to use the https module (instead of the http module) and you have to supply a certificate for the https server to startup properly.

Comment: To add to the above comment, changing your port to 443 sets up an HTTPS server as much as changing the port to 22 would make your program an SSH server (which is to say, it would not do that at all).

Answer (score 2):

You have the following error message:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::443
[...]
```

This message means that the port 443 is currently in use by some process.

You can check which process is actually using the said port by executing one of the many tools for network checking (such as `netstat` for Windows, `lsof` or `netstat` on Linux).

Refer to the manual for those tools to achieve the correct result, based upon your operating system.